# How to understand whether Stochastic Gradient Descent has converged?

Tags: gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent, convex

I am using SGD to solve for MSE function. My training set is around 50K, and I am monitoring the gradient at every epoch (once a pass is completed over all the training data). I played around a lot with the step sizes however I don't think they make that big of a difference. After running for 30 iterations, I don't think I have seen any convergence based on the gradient values. The norm of the gradient values change around 0.1 to 0.01. Not a constant decrease but it is erratic.

I am aware that it is not converging to optimal, I am okay with an approximate converge. I am just not really sure how to understand whether 0.1 norm(gradient) is close to the optimal and is relatively a good approximation or not.
[image]

Comment: 30 iterations or 30 epochs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming by 30 iterations you mean 30 epochs. And every epoch has a number of iterations. If that is the case it would help you to plot the loss function after every epoch and check it's behaviour.

If it falls for a while and then keeps on rising and falling it is possible that it has found a local minima and is stuck around that.

If the trend shows a steady fall throughout and does not change after increasing the number of epochs/iterations it is possible that it is near a global minima.

A visual representation of the loss will help you in understanding how your SGD is behaving.

Comment: In fact, many algorithms have something like an early stopping criterion of the form 'if the loss function did not move by more than $\epsilon$ over the last $k$ epochs / iterations then stop' and $\epsilon$ and $k$ are in fact hyperparameters but with senseful standard values (i.e. $\epsilon = 0.00001$ and $k=10$ or so you should be good in the sense that I would rather play around with other hyperparameters of the model instead of the parameters of the optimization)

Comment: @Saksham Thanks for your reply! Yes I mean 30 epochs, and basically at each epoch I am using each example in the training set once, so the number of iterations is going to be equal to the size of the training set. I ran for 50 epochs recently, and added the visual representation of the loss function to the question - which is basically MSE. However I couldn't make any sense out of it. I am slowly decreasing alpha to get a convergence, but that also doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I should increase the number of epochs?

Comment: @Aybike I do see a trend a gradual downward trend in the MSE. You should try increasing the number of epochs and that trend might be more visible. Sometimes, the loss function gets stuck at a local minima and we need to increase the learning rate to get it out of there. I would suggest you to experiment with your learning rate and try out 'cyclical learning rates' to encounter that. Also what is the model that you are using? If it is a neural network, adding more layers and making the function more complex might give better decrease in MSE with SGD.